# Is there such thing as the Gorensteinification of a one-dimensional local ring?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

That is, given $A$ local, reduced and one-dimensional, is there a finite extension $A\to B$ where $B$ is Gorenstein?

Comment: If the normalization is finite, you could take that. Maybe your situation is a bit more specific than formulated in the question (e.g. things are easier for noetherian rings). Also, you probably want to require some sort of universal property? (I took the liberty of latexifying the question)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the normalization.  In particular I'm trying to stick to S2 and seminormal rings only.

Comment: In other words, can I get a finite extension of A that is G1, S2, and seminormal?  There are ways to make A seminormal and S2.

Comment: It is helpful to include such relevant information (and background which can possibly steer the answer in the direction you want) into the question.

Comment: +1 for "Gorensteinification".

Comment: Thanks Matthias.  I should have asked a more specific question.  I understand that normalization improves the codimension one structure very nicely.  I'm looking for a slightly weaker operation that extends A into B where B is G1 and S2 but not necessarily R1 and S2.

Comment: A would be of arbitrary dimension, a reduced affine ring over a field.